# Was Ahch-To such a mystery?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-last-jedi

In *Star Wars: The Last Jedi*, we see that Ahch-To is where Luke was hiding  and the same place

> has the ancient Jedi temple. Also, while showing the tree branch shelf to Rey, he says that this was built many many years ago just for the purpose of storing the ancient Jedi texts.

Considering all this, wouldn't the other members of the force (Leia, Maz Kanata, Kylo Ren etc) know that Ahch-To could have possibly been where Luke is hiding? Instead of going to the trouble of hiding/finding the map to his location, couldn’t the Resistance or The First Order just send out their army on a hunt

> to the historic Jedi planet?

Comment: I cleaned this up and masked the spoilers. If I changed something, and it isn't what you meant to say, feel free to change those parts back. (try to leave the spoiler tags though, that helps people who read the lists of questions)

Comment: There might be an arguement that Luke felt like he had to hide the location from others, because being the first Jedi temple, it may hold information and/or have great power beyond what viewers saw in TLJ--it might explain why Snoke needed to use Ren to make contact.

Comment: Also early on their were reports of The Knights of Ren coming to the Island and attacking Luke. Recantly, Rian Johnson confirmed he had to make some big cuts to TLJ. One scene he describes is a final test for Rey. So maybe TKoR were a mirrage for her to test her loyalty/skills, but if not, it would suggest Ren knew where they were...

Answer (score 14):

## The legend of "The First Jedi Temple" was probably known to all (trained) Jedi, but at that point, Luke was the only Jedi left.

**And even Luke didn't know where it was exactly.**

Han says this in *Episode VII: The Force Awakens*:

> People that knew him best think he **went looking** for the First Jedi Temple.

The "went looking" part implies that Luke had an idea where to start, but didn't know it's exact location.

You mention a few specific people:

- **Leia** is force-sensitive, but was never "trained" as a Jedi.
- **Maz** is old and wise, and claims to *know* the Force (she is considered "Force-sensitive"), but she definitely doesn't claim to be a Jedi, or to have been trained in the force in any official capacity.
- **Kylo Ren** was trained by Luke, who might have told him about The First Jedi Temple, but since he didn't know its exact location, he wouldn't have been able to tell Kylo Ren.

Comment: Maz is force-sensative http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Maz_Kanata

Comment: @DarthLocke thanks for that reminder. I corrected it to say she's force-sensitive, but still not Jedi or officially trained

Comment: No worries. She's a character that I think has been under-used thus far!